# Visual Studio REALLY wants to create a database diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a VS "weirdness" I am unable to solve or explain.

Every now and again (with no consistency of action I am doing at the time) Visual Studio prompts me if I want to add database diagramming elements (similar to how SQL Manager would ask you if you chose to add a DB diagram for the first time.). It then asks me about 10-15 times within a half minute.

**Exact text of dialog:**

> "This server does not have one or more of the database objects
>   required to use database diagramming. Do you wish to create them?
>   Yes/No/Help"

Is there a way to ask it to be quiet?

Comment: I have never ever encountered this behaviour from Visual Studio. Though I know of the Data Source toolbox similar behaviour. Yet if you have set a data source for use with databindings, perhaps it might be a direction toward which to look.

Having the precise message could help get any further into our investigation. Is there any further details about an exception or so, even though I know it isn't one?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Will ... no exception but exact dialog text editted into question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offending tool window was the Server Explorer. Since closing it I have not had this behaviour re-occur. Still not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 14):

Bug report here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536426/database-diagramming-creation-dialog-keeps-popping-up-during-the-checkout-of-any-file

Apparently a bug in the pending changes window when using the filter by solution option. Very annoying! Turning off the filtering worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

VS seems to be pretty keen on crawling sub folders, I'd suggest that with the Explorer open it's trying to read that folder repeatedly on failure.
Letting Sql management create the elements (that don't do much harm anyway) should make it all go away.

Comment: Unfortunately the VS "gnome" keeps asking whether I say yes or no. But thankie Mr 42 ;)

Comment: Ah well, worth a try. See you at work when you are feeling better :)

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same strange issue several times. And yes, you are right I kept my server explorer active while working with linq. What triggered the popup was when I right clicked on the solution element within the solution explorer.

Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

For me, closing DatabaseExplorer, disabling solution filter etc. simply did not work. Running VS Ultimate 2012 Update 4.

After some research, the following seem to work, at least it stopped complaining ^^ Create in destination database this function:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION fn_diagramobjects()
   RETURNS [int]
   WITH EXECUTE AS 'dbo'
   AS 
   BEGIN
       RETURN 255;
   END
```