# Visual Studio popping up database diagramming dialog all the time

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I have recently switched source control for a solution I am working on from SVN to git (using the TFS git tools for VS found here [VS Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)).  Since doing that, when I now right click on my solution in VS it pops up the database diagramming dialog box for every connection string in the config file for the startup project.  The exact message is

**Microsoft Visual Studio**
*This server does not have one or more of the database objects required to use database diagramming.  Do you wish to create them?*
**Yes   No   Help**

I am using VS 2012 and the boxes pop up consistently when I right click on the solution (even when I select "No" it will pop it up again when I next right click). I have seen the possible solutions to this problem in this question [Visual Studio REALLY wants to create a database diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393188/visual-studio-really-wants-to-create-a-database-diagram) but with the git tools for VS there is no "Filter by Solution" option (which was the work a round suggested in that question).  Any ideas or suggestions welcome!